# How can I use A2DP Sink and microphone simultaniously on my bluetooth headsets?

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, bluetooth-speaker

I have a couple of really cool headsets that are both Bluetooth. One is like a beanie that has Bluetooth speakers built in (by Rotibox) and the other one is just a regular headset by Bluedio which is called a Turbine. Both of these headsets have A2DP Sink in them which sounds really good. However, I have Skype calls sometimes and it's nice to be able to talk to people from another room. I also would like to be able to do voice recordings with them which I do often. The problem is that when I set the headset to H2DP Sink it can't access the microphone. If I set the microphone to the high fidelity feedback it switches the speaker to HSP/HFP. Can I fix this and use H2DP Sink and the high fidelity feedback simultaniously? I was able to do this sometimes on Ubuntu Unity 16.10.

I am using Pulseaudio 10.0 on Ubuntu 17.10 with the Deepin Desktop Environment.

Comment: You can't. Reason see in my answer to the Q above.